Annotation @Valid doesn't work in my REST app
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

Why if I send a negative age or a blank name the @Valid annotation doesn't work and the person saves to database?
There is the following JSON that is sent to the server.
{
    "name": "",
    "age": -30
}

@Entity Person :
@Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Name mustn't be empty!")
    @Size(min = 2, max = 20, message = "Name must be between 2 and 20 characters long!")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Age must be greater than 0!")
    private int age;

Controller method:

@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> create(@RequestBody @Valid Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            StringBuilder errorMsg = new StringBuilder();

            List<FieldError> errors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
            for (FieldError error : errors) {
                errorMsg.append(error.getField()).append(" - ").append(error.getDefaultMessage()).append(";");
            }

            throw new PersonNotCreatedException(errorMsg.toString());
        }

        personService.savePerson(person);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }



org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors

You did not show the full controller class, but I suppose you miss @Validated annotation for it.

Let me guess only jakarta.validation-api on the classpath instead of using the spring-boot-starter-validation?

Are you sure you have a dependency ?
Gradle:
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

Maven:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

I advise you not to use entity as the request body and not to add annotations for validation in the entity. Better create PersonCreateRequest in put validate logic there and then match it with the entity:
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> create(@RequestBody @Valid PersonCreateRequest requestBody, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            StringBuilder errorMsg = new StringBuilder();

            List<FieldError> errors = bindingResult.getFieldErrors();
            for (FieldError error : errors) {
                errorMsg.append(error.getField()).append(" - ").append(error.getDefaultMessage()).append(";");
            }

            throw new PersonNotCreatedException(errorMsg.toString());
        }

        personService.savePerson(requestBody); // use Mapper in service

        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
    }


Thank you. Looks like I was too tired to notice it. Thanks for advice I appreciate it.

Consider using @Validated annotation at the top of the controller together with the validation maven dependency, unless you're already using the starter-web one:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>


please implement proper dependency in your pom.xml file
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>

for springboot maven project
